# By using listview see first string array item in List view and detail string array item in second activity

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

I have two `string array` . one of string array have `listview` item and
second array have detail description of `listview` item. When I clicked
on `listitem` in `listview` then I want to show detail description of
that `listitem` in second `activity`.

---

```
<string-array name="ListItem">
        <item>Gameplay Intro</item>
        <item>Enable the Leaderboard System</item>
        <item>Extra Moves and Features</item>
        <item>Learn work of Super Jewels </item>
        <item>Watch Out from The Dynamite</item>
        <item>Hidden Tricks</item>
    </string-array>

 <string-array name="Description">
        <item>detail 1 </item>
        <item>detail 2 System</item>
        <item>detail 3</item>
        <item>detail 4</item>
        <item>detail 5</item>
        <item>detail 6</item>
    </string-array>
```

ListActivity code:

```
public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static String[] listitems;
    ListView lvStatus;
    private NativeExpressAdView nativeExpressAdView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
        lvStatus = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvStatus);
        listitems=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ListItem);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listitems);
        lvStatus.setAdapter(adapter);
        lvStatus.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ListActivity.this,ShowActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Description show activity code:

```
public class ShowActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static String[] descriptions;
    TextView tvDetail;
    String listitems[];
    int intposition = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show);
        descriptions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Description);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.list_content,descriptions);
        intposition = getIntent().getIntExtra("position", 0);
        tvDetail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDetail);
        tvDetail.setText((CharSequence) adapter);
        tvDetail.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you  are getting position on click in this method:

```
@Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ListActivity.this,ShowActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

save that position and display data with same position from another array. 
there are plenty of ways to do that, one of them is:

`i.putExtra("selected_item", position);`